# ScrollView problem in Motorola Milestone

Tags: java, android

I have multiple listviews, all of them with scrollbars. Everything works great, tested in alot of emulators and a couple of phones... except in Motorola Milestone with 2.1. As i said, i tried it with the emulator in 2.1 and newer (i'm using 1.6 SDK) and i had no problem whatsoever, except when i try it with a physical Milestone. There, the scrollbar doesn't shows and, more important, i can't even scroll on the ListView.

Anyone has a clue on why is this happening?

Comment: What if you try the Milestone emulator http://developer.motorola.com/ ? If the error happens there it will be easier to debug; if it does not, it could be a problem on that specific handset.

Comment: Just tried it, it works fine on the Milestone emulator, so what could it be!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a 2.x thing. My layout had

```
<scrollview>
    <listview/>
</scrollview>
```

so my scroll stopped working. The phones i had in that time where all 1.x, the only with a 2.x system was the Milestone and hence the illusion that it was a Milestone problem. Weird thing is, in 2.x emulator it worked fine, so i assumed it wasn't a 2.x problem, i thought that simulator behavor would be consistent with phone behavor.